# Android : sliding drawer from top

Tags: android

I program in android app with android studio. I would like to try to make the same top sliding drawer like this that is in the app of "airbnb". I tried with sliding drawer  but I don't know how to start first because the sliding drawer component of android is "depracated" after API 17. I also tried with navigation drawer but it is on the side and not from top to bottom. 
I don't think that the navigation drawer or drawer layout could help.

Thanks a lot !
 If someone has an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this library: [Link](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

There are instructions about how to make this panel slide from top in the readme file.